# Subgroup analyses

Tags: repeated-measures

1200 pregnant patients were asked by the doctor/nurse if they smoke or not. Once the patient admits to smoking she is referred to quit smoking clinic. In the quit smoking clinic they are offered nicotine replacement therapy.

The questions are:

1. In the women who use nicotine replacement therapy do their babies do better than ones who refuse nicotine replacement therapy?
2. How do we test statistical significance?

Comment: Can you provide more info regarding the data? Which scale-levels? Are both binary variables like: treatment (replacement-therapy/no-replacement-therapy) and baby(does-better/does-not-better)? Then you need to use Chi-Square test.

Answer (score 2):

If the intent is to measure the impact of the therapy, I'm afraid there is no way you can answer those questions with this situation.  Because the women get to choose nicotine replacement therapy, this "variable" will be highly correlated with other information about the women (including, obviously, a preparedness to change their behaviour for health outcomes).  No statistical wizadry can separate out the impact of the therapy from that other unobserved information.

Even if you do a Chi-Square test as @jokel suggests, and it comes up with a significant difference between the groups, there is *no* reason to believe the nicotine replacement therapy was responsible, as opposed to whatever the women had in common that made them accept the therapy.

To answer the question of the impact of the therapy, you would need to divide the women who are prepared to take the therapy into two further groups - ones who really get it, and ones who are given a placebo instead.  Then you could compare the relative health of the babies of the women in those two groups.  You would need good advice on the ethics of such an experiment before going in this direction.  My hunch is that it would be unacceptable ethically.

---

On the other hand... if you don't mind the therapy effect being completely confounded with willingness to take therapy, you can measure the difference in health of babies in the two groups.  The test for the difference will depend on the scale that babies' health is measured on.